# Remove theme folder name from codeigniter URL

Tags: codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

[image]I have pages inside a folder named frontend/page and url shows like `www.domain.com/frontend/page/home`.

How do I change it to `www.domain.com/home`
Also the entry home is dynamic it could be about us or contact
My .htaccess file is

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|uploads|documentation|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please do it with Routing

Comment: i dont know how to do it

Comment: refer this => https://www.guru99.com/codeigniter-url-routing.html

Comment: didn't worked for me:(

Comment: show me your code so far in routes.php

Comment: added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect any page to it's corresponding controller which is in `frontend/page` sub-directory, you could modify the routes like below :

```
$route['(:any)'] = "frontend/page/$1";
```

Comment: I tested it on my own Codeigniter directory, with the same htaccess config as yours, and it works. Could you provide the directory structure of your project?